# Retrieve info from API when entering ISBN number Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

Firstly I know I have some reading to do with this but I was looking to see what would be a rails way of going about this

I am going to build a simple book library where you can add books, but rather than manually input all the info via a long form, it would be nice if i can just enter the ISBN number and retrieve all the info via an api. I believe Google data has such an api? or does anyone use anything else? This will be my first time using an api so any advice/resources that would assist me would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a service providing exactly  what you are looking for - http://isbndb.com/docs/api/20-structure.html

Rails Code:

```
require 'open-uri'
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def searchbook
     resp = open("http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=#{YOUR_API_KEY}&results=details&index1=isbn&value1=#{params[:isbn]}")
     doc = Nokogiri.XML(resp.read)
     # ... process response here
  end
end
```

Read about nokogiri's parsing capabilities [here](http://nokogiri.org/)
As for what an api actually is and how it works i think [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35939/how-do-web-apis-work) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Kai, do you know of any good resources that explain the whole call to an api request?

Comment: This might be a good starting point - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/35939/how-do-web-apis-work

Comment: Just a question, is it better to deal with JSON data instead of XML?

Comment: XML is a very powerful markup language, json on the other hand is easier to read for the human eye and uses less characters to structure data. So for an api i would go for json. *But* if you plan on using a  library it may as well depend on how good the library exposes the underlying data.